# Intershop7 - remote pipeline debugging - client not registered exception

Tags: remote-debugging, intershop

We have a problem with remote pipeline debugging.

Setup is as follows (test-live system) - 3 nodes (2 on same host, 1 on another host), webadapter installation on host itself. Setup done on RedHat linux virtual machines.
Intershop Studio 4.9.0.9 (latest at this moment) running on Windows 10.

Single breakpoint is defined prior to connecting to remote system. Upon connection few messages are exchanged through SOAP interface (first SessionMgmtService, DomainService, UserMgmtService and then PXIService URLs are targeted).

Last message before exception looks like this:

Request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<m:setBreakOnException xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:m="http://enfinity.intershop.com/namespaces/soap/com/intershop/beehive/core/internal/bos/pxi">
<clientId xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:base64">rO0ABXcEAAAAAQ==</clientId>
<flag xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:base64">rO0ABXcBAQ==</flag>
</m:setBreakOnException>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<enfinity:SessionID xmlns:enfinity="http://enfinity.intershop.com/namespaces/soap" value="VIuTJ5Xq6UyXJ8mc2TjiDmjgK79taeha4jnsE2uk"/>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<m:setBreakOnExceptionResponse xmlns:m="http://enfinity.intershop.com/namespaces/soap/com/intershop/beehive/core/internal/bos/pxi">
<result/>
</m:setBreakOnExceptionResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And next message contains error:

Request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<m:clearAllBreakpoints xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:m="http://enfinity.intershop.com/namespaces/soap/com/intershop/beehive/core/internal/bos/pxi">
<clientId xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:base64">rO0ABXcEAAAAAQ==</clientId>
</m:clearAllBreakpoints>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<enfinity:SessionID xmlns:enfinity="http://enfinity.intershop.com/namespaces/soap" value="x-OadAF9eiSfdF0LSlDrXfx3uNdkOnzNcVHnxLfP"/>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>PXIService::clearAllBreakpoints(): exception occured during method invocation; nested exception is: 
    com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.bos.pxi.PXIBORegisterException: Client is not registered</faultstring>
<detail>
<enfinity:Exception xmlns:enfinity="http://enfinity.intershop.com/namespaces/soap">
<message>Client is not registered</message>
<type>com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.bos.pxi.PXIBORegisterException</type>
</enfinity:Exception>
</detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here are just the messages:

PXIService::clearAllBreakpoints(): exception occured during method invocation; nested exception is: 
    com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.bos.pxi.PXIBORegisterException: Client is not registered

Next connection attempt either result in same message as above or as this one:

PXIService::setBreakOnException(): exception occured during method invocation; nested exception is: 
    com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.bos.pxi.PXIBOHandlingException: Only one client can register for 'break on exception'.

We have used Intershop 6.4 before and did not come to such problems at initial connect attempt after server restart - it was possible for debugger to break occasionally bot not like this what happens in version 7.

Local pipeline debugging usually works, but it also can break if quick actions are performed on break points - like enabling and disabling them again.

Is there any kind of configuration or workaround for this situation? (I do not have 7.9 installation to verify behavior on older 7.x versions.)

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Usually dont try debugging test or live systems, but have you tried downgrading studio? From the previous question there seems to be some bugs in the latest version.

Comment: Tested with version 4.7.3 initially, and with 4.6.1 after your comment. Same results.

Comment: i think best is to submit a ticket to support, i dont know enough about the pipeline debugger. Im sure support can help.